# Redisson Cusing connectionpool

Tags: java, dictionary, redis, redisson

[baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/redis-redisson) lists several benefits of Redisson as Redis client. So I decided to use it.
For POC purpose I was using single node instance may be later will switch to some other. Checked [Redisson connection pool](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/blob/master/redisson/src/main/java/org/redisson/connection/pool/ConnectionPool.java) but it requires master slave config. How do I make it work with single instance?
I was expecting get() method from the pool to return RedisClient but it returns future.
Also this method takes RedisCommand as parameter. I was expecting once I get RedisClient I can do some map operations on it like shown at [Rmap example](https://redisson.org/redis-java-client-with-code-example.html). Is there anywhere a documentation that I can follow that shows how to use RedisCommand but first of all what is it(working code example would be great)?

My use case is simple - The request that my service receives requires heavy processing so want to cache the results against each request. 
Also sometimes if the response is too large we also batch the response. 
Let's say Req1 request results in Res1(without batching) -> I want to save in Redis Map, Res1 as value against Req1. Now let's say that but since Res1 was huge and we had to batch it and send just page 1 with link of page 2. In that case I want to save both full response Res1 and first page say just 100 entries of the Res1 in Redis. Naming convention that I am using is below:

```
    key                   value
    Req1:allPages          Res1
    Req:page1              page 1 of Res1
    Req:page2              page 2 of Res1

..
```

Similarly for other requests saving both paged and full response if already not present in Redis.

Is my naming convention standard or some other pattern is in vogue? And how do i use Redisson Connection pool with Single Node. And later when I switch to say Master-slave how do to this migration? Also What is RedisCommand and how do I create and use it?

I am using latest version of Redisson:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.redisson</groupId>
        <artifactId>redisson</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

> And how do i use Redisson Connection pool with Single Node

You don't need to maintain connection pool by your self. Just define configuration for Single node like [explained here](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/2.-Configuration#26-single-instance-mode)

> Also What is RedisCommand and how do I create and use it?

You don't need to use low-level object like RedisClient. Just find appropriate API for Redis commands [here](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/11.-Redis-commands-mapping)